# Hyperledger on IBM Cloud, chaincode launched and waiting for registration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

### Code

Currently I followed [this article](https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/platform-deployment/) to develop my BNA to IBM blockchain cloud platform (started plan). Unluckily, I got the error when I try to run this line of code:

```
composer network start -c admin@mynetwork-fabric -A admin -C ./creds/admin-pub.pem -f delete.card -n my_network -V 0.0.4
```

### Error

I am very sure that all parameters are good, the full errors are:

> Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses 
>   from any peers. 
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN:
>   premature execution - chaincode (my_network:0.0.4) launched and
>   waiting for registration

Or sometimes the error is:

> Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses 
>   from any peers. 
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error:
>   REQUEST_TIMEOUT

I understand sometimes maybe there is a timeout, but I do not really got the `launched and waiting for registration` error.

### P.S.

- My hyperledger composer version is 0.19.
- I also view [this deploying tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-business-network-on-free-ibm-blockchain-starter-plan-93fafb3dd997), there might be some different commands, because of the different versions of Hyperledger Composer. I checked the composer hep to transfer the commands to running on composer 0.19.

### Solution:

1. down grade `composer-cli` to 0.18.1
2. change your package.json, `composer-cli` to 0.18.1
3. `npm install` to create new bna
4. reinstall
5. restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IBM Cloud Starter Plan, then you need to be using v0.18.1 of Composer not v0.19.

Also, this is the doc you should be following:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/develop_starter.html#deploying-a-business-networks-on-starter-plan